# System.StackOverflowException was unhandled

Tags: c#

Please help, I'm confused I do not know why the error logs
`System.StackOverflowException` was unhandled.

I keep getting an error on set LekID.
How would I that fix?

Here is the code:

```
public Lager(long lekID, string lek, string proizvojdac, int kolicina, double cena)
{
    LekID = lekID;
    Lek = lek;
    Proizvodjac = proizvojdac;
    Kolicina = kolicina;
    Cena = cena;

}

public long LekID   
{
    get { return LekID; }
    set { LekID = value; }
}
public string Lek
{
    get { return Lek; }
    set { Lek = value; }
}
public string Proizvodjac
{
    get { return Proizvodjac; }
    set { Proizvodjac = value; }
}
public int Kolicina
{
    get { return Kolicina; }
    set { Kolicina = value; }
}
public double Cena
{
    get { return Cena; }
    set { Cena = value; }
}
```

Comment: Several people have answered your question but as a general note be aware you can't catch a stack overflow because it happens in the framework rather than your code.

Answer (score 8):

You should give different names to your private variables and to your properties. Otherwise, your property is calling itself when you access it.

Example:

```
long _lekID;
public long LekID
{
    get { return _lekID; }
    set { _lekID = value; }
}
```

Or simply:

```
public long LekID { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 8):

```
public long LekID   
{
    get { return LekID; }
    set { LekID = value; }
}
```

This (and the other properties) cause a StackOverflowException, since you are assigning `value` to `LekID` over and over again.

You should add a field to the property and store the value there:

```
private long _lekID;
public long LekID   
{
    get { return _lekID; }
    set { _lekID = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The properties are calling themself. Try changing your properties like this:

```
public string Lek
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're calling the Lek property recursively in both the setter and the getter

Either introduce a backing field:

```
private string lek;

public string Lek
{
    get { return this.lek; }
    set { this.lek = value; }
}
```

or use an Automatic Property:

```
public string Lek
{
    get; set;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Marking this community wiki as it is only an aside, but none of this would have happened if you'd been sufficiently lazy (that is often a virtue in programming, not a vice):

```
public long LekID {get;set;}
public string Lek {get;set;}
public string Proizvodjac {get;set;}
public int Kolicina {get;set;}
public double Cena {get;set;}
```

less typing; no errors; and you've correctly exposed the API as properties so you can add validation / side-effects later if you need, and it'll work with binding APIs (which don't usually love fields).

Answer (score 0):

Try using code snippet like prop/ propfull,

the snippets will create the properties code automaticly